# Creating a simple readonly structure similar to DataTable

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple readonly structure similar to datatable structure , i will be using it to generate sql commands and i am looking for maximum performance the following is what i came up with, the idea is to generate  `Rows[]` from an `IList<T>`.

```
class Column
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string TableName { get; private set; }
        public bool IsPrimaryKey { get; private set; }
        public SqlDbType SqlType { get; private set; }
        public string SqlTypeString { get { return SqlType.ToString(); } }
        //etc..
        public Column(PropertyInfo propertyInfo){//init everything}
    }



class Cell
    {
        public Column Column { get; private set; }
        public object Value { get; private set; }

        public Cell(object Value,Column Column)
        {
            this.Column = Column;
            this.Value = Value;
        }
    }

class Row
    {
        public object[] Cells { get; private set; }
        public Row(Cell[] Cells)
        {
            this.Cells = new Cell[Cells.Count()];
            for (int i = 0; i < Cells.Count(); i++)
            {
                this.Cells[i] = Cells[i]; 
            }
        }
    }
```

each cell contains a reference to its column object which is i am not sure if its the right thing, i was wondering if dropping the column reference from the cell and using the object order to get the column reference is a better option, in other words i  want to micro optimize it since its a simple structure.

Comment: You shouldn't need a `Cell` class at all.  You can look at similar code that I wrote, with support for strong typing, at https://github.com/ShomreiTorah/Libraries/blob/master/ShomreiTorah.Singularity/Row.cs

Comment: Look at micro-ORMs like Dapper, which already do all of this for you.

Comment: There are a few obvious problems with what you're doing here, and I'm sure a number of problems that I can't see because I don't fully understand the purpose of this data structure. What problem are you trying to solve with this? Have you tried existing frameworks to see if they can solve the same problem better?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior making an orm, what i have achived so far is somthing like list.Update(o=>o.column1,o=>column2).Where(o=>o.id==o.id), i need to have such structure to avoid havaing a reference to the original object, in the where clause i analyse the expression tree and and parameters, with this structure its working great, i thought there has to be a better way

Comment: @SLaks i really want to keep it simple since i will be the only one using it, anything else other than getting rid of the cell object?

Comment: @user1492051: Again: have you tried the other frameworks that try to solve this problem? There's a good chance that they've come up with a "better way," so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. For example, [these extensions](http://efe.codeplex.com/) built on top of Entity Framework seem to accomplish the same thing you're going for. And I've heard great things about Dapper.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior there are some really good things in there thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to micro optimize it since its a simple structure.

That's not a valid reason to micro-optimize this structure.

Your class structure, as it stands, isn't even correct yet. First focus on *correctness*, then you can work on optimization.

For example, by returning the same `object[]` that you use internally, this is not the "readonly structure" you're claiming it to be. Someone can modify the elements of this array and mess things up royally.

With what you've said you're trying to do with this framework (analyzing expression trees to produce SQL queries, etc.), chances are that any optimization you do at this level wouldn't even be noticeable. But if you do want to begin optimizing, the right place to begin is by removing the calls to `.Count()` on your arrays. Use `.Length` instead.

But, as I mentioned in the comments on your question, I'd strongly suggest trying out existing frameworks first. Smarter people than you and I have put a lot of time and effort into them, and they're likely to do a better job than we can. :-)